# Enable OPAL_OUTPUT_VERBOSE in MPI

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I'm running few MPI jobs (OpenMPI), how do I get the verbose outputs that are mentioned in the source code (OPAL_OUTPUT_VERBOSE). I configured using --enable-debug and I run the application using this command

```
mpirun -np 4 -v myapp
```

I also tried using --debug / -d / --mca opal_verbose_output 10 in the mpirun command but am unable to print out the verbose messages. what is the correct way that I can the verbose output.

Thanks,
kris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option `opal_verbose_output` for `mca`. You can check which value you can set using `ompi_info -a` or `ompi_info -a | grep verbose` to find the right verbose option.